# Disable select items option in SPS 2013 List Webpart?

Tags: list, sharepoint-server

I want to disable the select items option, as users should only be able to view the items in modal view, but no option to do multiple select  or edit.

Therefore using css I tried disabling the class name: "ms-selectall-icon"
But that doesn’t take care of the entire row.

Moreover, if you place the cursor it will give you the option to select the item.
We don’t want the option to select item, but on the other side allowing users to click on the item name to open it in modal view.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint have OOTB option for this.

- Go to list
- Modify view which you want in list webpart.
- No go to '`Tabular View`' section
- Uncheck the box '`Allow individual item checkboxes`'
- Click Ok

[image: refer this]

- Go to your list view webpart
- In List webpart. you just need to select the view you just modified.
- There you go

Comment: spot on that is what I had already tried, but it doesnt works.

Comment: Do you have webpart in some new page ?

Comment: Its placed on my home page. Just refresh the webpart by changing the view to other view and then set it to display.aspx with your suggestions. Still cant see the effect.

Comment: Open the list, and change the view to your display view, see if it works there. (Not on Home page)

Comment: It works on the actual page - display.aspx (https://example.com/Lists/testform/Display.aspx

However, on homepage wondering why it doesnt reflect the changes.

Comment: Okay, do 1 thing, On HomePage, edit webpart in edit mode. select the view. below that you have option to edit. do it. do the above settings from answer, click okay, save all changes. and check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40766/discussion-between-gaurravs-and-jason).

Comment: glad it worked ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Normal way to achieve these use cases are by means of permissions.

Create a SharePoint Group which has read permission on the list. Then add users into that.